# Picture share in facebook is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"parth kausik", @"name", 
                                 imageview.image, @"picture",   
                                 nil];

  [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

hello guys these code is not working . it is not calling the request delegate and not uploading any picture.Do u have any idea..

Error is coming ....

```
error is:Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x6c592d0 {error=<CFBasicHash 0x6c55f70 [0x12a9b38]>{type = mutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x6c56130 [0x12a9b38]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x6c56820 [0x12a9b38]>{contents = "OAuthException"}
    3 : <CFString 0x6c567c0 [0x12a9b38]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x6c56720 [0x12a9b38]>{contents = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."}
    6 : <CFString 0x6c59020 [0x12a9b38]>{contents = "code"} = 2500
}
}
Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.
```

Comment: check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10024056/705559).

Comment: Not yet worked ... requestWithGraphPath method is not calling..

Comment: are you call the upload function after the fblogin ?

Comment: I m already login , called this method after login on button click.

Comment: implement `- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` and check what is the error ?

Comment: If method is not calling then how its delegate can be called.

Comment: what do you mean by the method is not calling ?!!

Comment: requestWithGraphPath method is not calling  while facebook dialog is working perfectly...

Comment: and whats make you think that its doesn't been called ??! you don't think that the xcode is ignoring this line .. do you ? :) if you put a breakpoint on its line is it possible it never been hit !!

Comment: error is:Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)"

Comment: ok show me now how is your upload function ?

Comment: [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];

Comment: no i mean the whole funtion ? u still using the same one you write it above or you are using mine (in the answer link) ?

Comment: and the image ?! just take my function Im sure it will work .. and don't forget to upvote my answer :)

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"273564619349421",@"api_key",imageview.image,@"source", @"parth kausik",@"name",[facebook accessToken],@"access_token",nil];
  

  [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];

Comment: Man don't post your api_key to public .. its a secure key .. and plzzzzzzz just write the params as in my function and you will get what you want :)

Comment: Give answer I will accept if it works.. and also upvote u.

Answer (score 1):

Add Social framework and then Import classes, and Add following code

```
 SLComposeViewController *facebookPostVC =[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook ];
[facebookPostVC setInitialText:@"iPhone Application"];
[facebookPostVC addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",link]]];
[facebookPostVC addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
[self presentViewController:facebookPostVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Note: this is work for Xcode 4.5

Answer (score 0):

just write the params and set the image as describe in the following function :

```
- (void) uploadImageWithName : (NSString*)name
{
    NSString *img = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",name];
    UIImage *uploadImage = [UIImage imageNamed:img];//you can get the image on other ways also like imageView.image

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [fb accessToken], 
                                   @"access_token",nil];

    [params setObject:uploadImage forKey:@"source"];

    [fb requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                             andParams: params
                         andHttpMethod: @"POST"
                           andDelegate:self];

}
```

Comment: I have already written parameter and set the image as u have described but the facebook domain error says to reauthorise it. How can we do that

Comment: check the access token .. is it nil ?

Comment: and be carful that you need to call `- (void) uploadImageWithName : (NSString*)name` after the `fbDidLogin` is being fired ?

Comment: accesstoken is null ..please come on chat in room iphone developers

Comment: i told you .. you need to call it after tha fbDidLogin being fired to get a valid access token ,, you said "I m already login" !

Comment: and in the `fbDidLogin` you get the [facebook accessToken] = nil ??!

Comment: yes I have got nil value of access token please come on chat I will discus there because we have to wait for 5 min to upload comment

Comment: what are the permissions you request to authorize ?